# Is there any book similar to "Halmos Naive Set Theory" in Category Theory?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, book-recommendation

When I wanted to learn set theory in high school, I found [Halmos Naive Set Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Set_Theory_(book))  book very readable and understandable. But now, at university, I have been searching for a similar book in category theory, but I haven't found any book like that until now.

What is your suggestion?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What sorts of features are you looking for? There is a nice MO thread [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/69251/is-mac-lane-still-the-best-place-to-learn-category-theory).

Comment: @Hoot thanks for the link. I had read that before I asked this question, but I can't read all of them! It's difficult to me to explain explicitly that what features I'm looking for, but every body who read Haloms's book probably knows that what features I'm looking for!

Comment: I do wish that people would/could say more about the books they're recommending. As it stands it seems to me like you're aiming at a very specific set of people, but maybe such a person will turn up.

Comment: http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/maclanecat.pdf

Comment: http://math.mit.edu/~dspivak/teaching/sp13/CT4S.pdf

Comment: @WillJagy I'm very grateful to you for the links, but why you didn't put these comments as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right; at college level, before, especially, algebraic topology, you are probably best off with something like [SPIVAK](http://math.mit.edu/~dspivak/teaching/sp13/CT4S.pdf). Also available as a pdf is [Mac Lane](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/maclanecat.pdf), written by one of those who invented category theory, as something of an outgrowth of homological algebra. The latter is probably intended for graduate students. Meanwhile, it would not be surprising if there were still other books, at various levels. Category theory has become indispensable  for, say, algebraic geometry.

Some nice reviews for an introductory book: [CONCEPTUAL](http://fef.ogu.edu.tr/matbil/eilgaz/kategori.pdf)  then, with common author Lawvere [SETS](http://patryshev.com/books/Sets%20for%20Mathematics.pdf)

Comment: @Ab_Sh found two more. Since you are reading on your own, start with the lightest reading, probably Spivak.

Comment: At the first glance Shcanuel's book seems very interesting to me, but I found Mac Lan's book in the spirit of Halmos's book!

Answer (score 2):

Doing a Google search for
"naive category theory",
here  the first hit:

Fibered Categories and the Foundations of Naive Category Theory

www.jstor.org/stable/2273784
JSTOR
by J Bénabou - ‎1985 - ‎Cited by 191
OF NAIVE CATEGORY THEORY. JEAN BENABOU.

Introduction. Any attempt to give "foundations", for category theory or any domain in mathematics, could ...

Comment: [Here](http://artscidirectory.case.edu/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Benabou-Fibered.pdf) is the pdf file.

Comment: This is not going to be readable for a beginner,

Answer (score 2):

Leinster recently came out with a fantastic book

[Basic Category Theory, Tom Leinster, 2014](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1107044243)

It is shallow in terms of proofs but it is deep with examples. This really will help you understand category theory from whichever mathematics you may already know best.